# accessing certain rows in json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

guys i know it is dummy question but i spent a lot of hours and cant reach .. i ha ve json array and i want for example to access the elements of second row which are `lname2 fname2 90 feedback2` .. this is the array `var json = [ {
            "lname" : "lname1",
            "fname" : "fname1",
            "age" : 10,
            "feedback" : "feedback1"
        }, {
            "lname" : "lname2",
            "fname" : "fname2",
            "age" : 90,
            "feedback" : "feedback2"
        }, {
            "lname" : "lname3",
            "name" : "fname3",
            "age" : 30,
            "feedback" : "feedback3"
        }`

Comment: access like you would any element in an array.

Comment: `json[1].lname` `json[1].fname` ...

Answer (score 1):

You have an *array* of *objects* - so iterate the array, access the object properties:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log(json[i].fname);
}
```

To specifically access the second element of the array, specify the index:

```
var fname = json[1].fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access 2nd row by index

```
json[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
json[1].lname
json[1].fname
json[1].age
json[1].feedback
```

Also what ever you have posted is not a JSON its an parsed result of JSON. JSON is ultimately a string. all the data is converted into one big string. Later when you parse the json you will get the result as in your post.

---

**Explaining the code**

Note that variable json is like `var json = []` , this `[ ]` is used to create a array, Hence the variable `json` is an array and we can access the elements by inex

Here [1] referes to the index of the array. As your `json` is an array. We use index numbers to access the elements in the array. And the indexes start from 0. So your second element will be in the index 1, 3rd will be in 2 and so on...

Now `json[1]` will return the second element so..

```
 json[1] = {
            "lname" : "lname2",
            "fname" : "fname2",
            "age" : 90,
            "feedback" : "feedback2"
        }
```

note the `{ }` this refers to an object, this `{ }` is used to create an object. Now to access the property values of the object we use the `.` operator. hence the code `json[1].lname` , `json[1].fname` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this variable is not a JSON, but simply a javascript array of objects. To access a data in it, you'll have to use `json[X].lname` for exemple, where X is the index of the object you want to reach.

A JSON is a string of characters representing different type of data, such as arrays and objects. To decode such a string, you could use JSON.parse().

You can find more informations about JSON here : http://www.json.org/

Hope this helps!